# How to compute backpropagation gradient according chain rule for using vector/matrix differential?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, matrix, derivation

I have some problems for computing derivative for sum of squares error in backprop neural network.
For example, we have a neural network as in picture. For drawing simplicity, i've dropped the sample indexes.

Сonventions:

1. x - data_set input.
2. W - is a weigth matrix.
3. v - vector of product: W*x.
4. F - activation function vector.
5. y - vector of activated data
6. D - vector of answers
7. e - error signal
8. lower index is a variable(NxN) -  dimenstionality
9. higher [index] -  is a layer number.

[image: Structure of neural network]

Jacobian is defined as:

\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1(x_1)}{\partial x_1}&\dots&\frac{\partial f_1(x_N)}{\partial x_N}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\frac{\partial f_M(x_1)}{\partial x_1}&\dots&\frac{\partial f_M(x_N)}{\partial x_N}\end{pmatrix}

Let's have a look at the second layer and let's find derivative according chain rule:

Optimization error is sum of squared errors:

[image: Text]

The chain rule for second layer is :

[image: Text]

I'm going to derivate according rules founded here: https://fmin.xyz/docs/theory/Matrix_calculus/

[image] - 1xN - dimension

[image: Text] - NxN matrix

[image: Text] - NxN matrix (look at Jacobian)

[image: Text] - Nx2N Tensor product (try yourself for 2x2)

So the differential is:

[image: Text]

(You can verify equations according this service http://www.matrixcalculus.org/ or yourself using 2x2 dimension)

*Let' look at dimenstions: (1xN) x (NxN) x (NxN) x (Nx2N) = (1x2N)*

When we try to use gradient descent

[image: Text]

- The dimenstions will not be the same: **(NxN) = (NxN) - (1x2N)**

Therefore, we cannot update the coefficients according this.

Where did i make a mistake?
Any comments are welcomed. Thanks!